# wifi not working in ubuntu (installed on macbook)

Tags: 20.04, wireless, macbook-pro

Below is network adapter i see, but not able to use it

```
lspci -vvnn | grep -A 9 Network 
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM4360 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:4360] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Apple Inc. BCM4360 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [106b:0134]
    Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 256 bytes
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 18
    Region 0: Memory at c1b00000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=32K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel modules: bcma, wl
```

Comment: Is [this answer by Luis Alvaredo](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers/60395#60395) helpful?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My wireless/WiFi connection does not work. What information is needed to diagnose the issue?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers)

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there is some workaround available:
You'll first need to blacklist the b43 driver by adding a blacklist file to `/etc/modprobe.d/b43.conf` with the contents "blacklist b43". Then run `update-initramfs -u` and then install the `bcmwl-kernel-source package`.
After a reboot your wireless device should be available.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-drivers-common/+bug/2013236